# Separate date in the format {day-month-year}

Tags: php, function, datetime, output

I have a code that print the date in this format
`Sun, 09 Mar 2014 08:31:14 GMT`

I want to take the Date and shorten it so I can print

- the day
- the month
- the year

but I want to print each separately and I want to print the month in numbers

Here is the code I tried

```
$Date = $item->pubDate;
echo '.$Date.';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) of the `DateTimeClass`

```
<?php
$dt='Sun, 09 Mar 2014 08:31:14 GMT';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y G:i:s O', $dt);
echo "Day : ".$date->format('d'); // 09
echo "Month : ".$date->format('m'); //03
echo "Year : ".$date->format('Y'); //2014
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/116999)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [date](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($Date));
```

And if you want to echo one by one

```
$date_to_time = strtotime($Date);

//Day
echo date('d', $date_to_time);
//Month
echo date('m', $date_to_time);
//Year
echo date('Y', $date_to_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$date = '08/02/2014';
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
```